# Datatable - ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I add success function DataTable not fill up automaticly rows in table. When I remove success function everything is all right and datatable fill correctly data in table. I want to catch in response using getAccessMessageWithStatus message by status but if I do it like this datatable no filling rows. How I can do that?

```
$('#' + datatableName).DataTable({
  destroy: true,
  'bProcessing': false,
  'bServerSide': true,
  'ajax': {
    'url': URL,
    'data': filters,
    beforeSend: function() {
      loader.popup('show');
    },
    success: function(response) {
      getAccessMessageWithStatus(response);

    },
    complete: function() {
      $listContainer.show();
      $containerChoiseColumnsFilter.show();
      $(".containerRaportButtons").show();
      getLastSearches();
      getUses();
      loader.popup('hide');
    }
  },
  'sServerMethod': "POST",
  'columns': columns,
  'order': order,
  'responsive': true
});
```

Answers:

```
success: function(response) {
  getAccessMessageWithStatus(response);

},
```

Or:

```
"dataSrc": function(response) {

  if (response.status == false) {
    alert(response.msg);
    return [];
  }
  return response.aaData;
},
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove ";" after the function name into the code.

```
success: function (response) {
      getAccessMessageWithStatus(response)
},
```

Comment: Why? I ask only because I am interested in your reasoning!

Comment: Yes, Few days ago I have also faced same issue and after spending few hours I have found that ";" creates a issue.

Comment: This won't work in my case, it(success function) always causes datatables output null.

Comment: Can you please quote how and where did you found this reasoning

Comment: @Mbotet I don't remember exactly now because Its 2 year old answer. But I had faced this issue and after trying many solutions, this was worked for me.

Comment: @DharmeshGoswami don't worry. I had some trouble with some extra comma and just wanted to learn how this crazy fix worked.

Answer (score 4):

There is an event from DatatTable called **'xhr.dt'**. You can use it in that way.

```
$('#' + datatableName).on('xhr.dt', function(e, settings, json, xhr){
    getAccessMessageWithStatus(json);
}).DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    'bProcessing': false,
    'bServerSide': true,
    'ajax':
        {
            'url': URL,
            'data': filters,
            beforeSend: function () {
                loader.popup('show');
            },
            complete: function () {
                $listContainer.show();
                $containerChoiseColumnsFilter.show();
                $(".containerRaportButtons").show();
                getLastSearches();
                getUses();
                loader.popup('hide');
            }
       }
});
```

You shouldn't use success from ajax attribute because you will overwrite the success function from DataTable. See this piece of code from  query.dataTables.js

```
"success": function (json) {
    var error = json.error || json.sError;
    if ( error ) {
        _fnLog( oSettings, 0, error );
    }

    oSettings.json = json;
    callback( json );
}
```

You can notice that they have a callback inside this function. This callback triggers the function _fnCallbackFire and this call the event xhr.dt

For more information, go to this page
https://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr

Comment: This explains why I see nothing there once I use success. thanks. Better to use "initComplete"

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way:

```
"complete": function (json, type) { //type return "success" or "parsererror"
    if (type == "parsererror") {
        alert("parsererror");
    }
     ... 
}
```